# What is the difference between enable_pickling and pickle_suite in boost python?

Tags: python, c++, boost, pickle

I have a pretty big class that has ~40 attributes, but only 15 that are passed as arguments to the constructor:

```
class MyClass{
    /*40 attributes here*/
    MyClass(/*15 args here, the rest are initialized at default values*/);
};
```

I'm trying to implement pickle support for this class, and so far the [boost.python documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/python/doc/v2/pickle.html) seems to indicate that I can either implement an instance of the `pickle_suite` class, or I can just do `.enable_pickling()` and let python handle the rest. Is there any advantage in taking the time to implement all the `__getinitargs__` and stuff compared to just doing it with one line? As far as I understand, pickling is essentially converting the objects to a bunch of 1s and 0s and passing it around.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, looks like the normal python pickler can't copy the elements inside a container like a std::vector or a std::pair